# How to smoothly zoom in or out (Visual Basic)

Tags: performance, vba, zooming

I try to zoom in or out a picture in small steps until it fills the screen. My code:
            While I <> Math.Round(ZoomFactor, 2)
                If ZoomFactor >= 1 Then
                    I = I + 0.01
                    ZoomPicture(1.01)
                Else
                    I = I - 0.01
                    ZoomPicture(0.99)
                End If
                Me.PictureBox1.Update()
            End While
    Private Sub ZoomPicture(ZoomFactor)
        Dim BiggerImage As Bitmap
        BiggerImage = New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image, PictureBox1.Image.Width * ZoomFactor, PictureBox1.Image.Height * ZoomFactor)
        PictureBox1.Image = BiggerImage
    End Sub

This works, but the zooming is a bit jerky (not smooth). I would like it to be like a movie (so mnimum 24 zooms/seconds).

Is there a better way to achieve this? But not too complicated (I think using DirectX is very complicated, or isn't it?)

Thanks a lot for an useful information

Marc

Comment: `Is there a better way to achieve this?` 
Probably you may achive that with [XLL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687883.aspx). The problem lies in VBA itself, i.e.VBA Engine performance.

Comment: What is XLL? I know fortran, colbol, basic, pascal, visual basic. I prefer not to learn a new language at my age.

Comment: Please, have a look at the link referenced with "XLL". It's an SDK supporting C/C++ as native languages, hence, others after porting header files. Maybe someone already has ported XLL SDK into one of your preffered languages.

Comment: I don't know C or C++. Is there no solution in VB?

Comment: `others (languages) after porting header files. Maybe someone already has ported XLL SDK into one of your preffered languages.`

Answer (score 0):

I use the following now:

```
While PictureBox1.Image.Height < ScreenHeight And (Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.Timer - StartTime) < ScreenSaverDuration
      PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(Image1, PictureBox1.Image.Width * 1.003, PictureBox1.Image.Height * 1.003)
      Me.PictureBox1.Update()
End  While
```

This works reasonably well